# Security Program - Splitting Files

Tags: security, file, permissions, architecture

How would you go about describing the architecture of a "system" that splits a sensitive file into smaller pieces on different servers in order to protect the file?

Would we translate the file into bytes, and then distribute those bytes onto different servers?  How would you even go about getting all the pieces back together in order to call the original file back (if you have the correct permissions)?

This is a theoretical problem that I do not know how to approach.  Any hints at where I should start?

Comment: Looking to implement BitTorrent?

Comment: @0xA3: I was almost looking for a brief documentation of architecture of BitTorrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an authoritative answer but you will get many here as replies which provides partial answers to your question. It may just give you some idea.

My guess is, you would be creating a custom file system.

Take a look at various filesystems like

- GmailFS: http://richard.jones.name/google-hacks/gmail-filesystem/gmail-filesystem.html
- pyfilesystem: http://code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem/
- A distributed file system in python: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/koboldfs

Hence architecturally, it will be very similar to way a typical distributed filesystem is implemented.

1. It should be a client/server architecture in master/slave mode. You will have to create a custom protocol for their communication.
2. Master process is what you will talk to for retrieving / writing your files.
3. Slave fs would be distributed across different servers which will keep a tagged file which contains partial bits of information of a file
4. Master fs will contain a per file entry that locates all sequence of tagged data distributed across various slave servers.
5. You could have redundancy with a tagged data being store on multiple server.
6. Communication protocol will have to be designed to allow multiple servers to respond back to requested tagged data. Master fs simply picks one and ignores others in the simplest case.
7. Usual security requirements needs to be respected for storing and communicating this information across servers.

You will be most interested in secure distributed filesystem implemented in Python : **Tahoe**

- http://tahoe-lafs.org/~warner/pycon-tahoe.html
- http://tahoe-lafs.org/trac/tahoe-lafs

Comment: @thesimpledesigner: I have updated my answer to add a link to tahoe which seems close to what you want.

Comment: Could we potentially use hash tables to keep track of different pieces of one data piece?  I do not know enough about hash tables, but would that be a distributed hash table file system?

Comment: @thesimpledesigner: My understanding is both master / client keeps a look up table. This needs to be heavily optimized as it would form the core of the lookup. Master keeps tags of partitioned main file while client will keep the tags of all files that it stores.